# output array length greater than input array after for in loop (undefined values)

Tags: javascript

Here's my html:

```
<div id='test'>
<input name="M1" size="3" value="1">
<input name="M2" size="3" value="2">
<input name="M3" size="3" value="3">
</div>
```

here's my javascript:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
var arr = test.querySelectorAll('input');
var arr2 =[];
for (i in arr) {arr2.push(arr[i].value) ;}
```

this my final array arr2:

```
["1","2","3",undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined]
```

the point is that arr.length is 3 but arr2.length is 9, six elements are undefined. Could you please explain why and better way to achieve it?

Comment: `for (i in arr) { console.log(i); arr2.push( arr[i].value ); }`I suspect that this may make it clearer. Incidentally: `let arr2 = Array.from( test.querySelectorAll('input') ).map( (inputEl) => inputEl.value )` would be a less complex way of achieving your (apparent) desired end result. Also: see the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) documentation on MDN.

Comment: try `for (const i of arr) { arr2.push(i.value) }` instead, `in` is not a collection iterator,  but `of` is..

Answer (score 1):

A [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop in JavaScript loops over the *enumerable* properties of an object. Here, you are trying to use `for..in` on `arr`, which is **not** an array, it's a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (as that's the return value of querySelectorAll).

A NodeList has the enumerable properties of:

```
0
1
2
length
item
entries
forEach
keys
values
```

As you can see, it doesn't just contain the indexes of `arr`, but rather all the enumerable properties. This means your `for..in` loop will go through each of these. That's why you get `undefined` in your array as `arr['length'].value` for example will give you `undefined`.
For looping a NodeList, you can use a regular for loop, a `for..of` loop or [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach):

```js
const test = document.getElementById('test');
const nodes = test.querySelectorAll('input');
const arr2 = [];
for (const input of nodes) {
  arr2.push(input.value);
}
console.log(arr2);
```

```html
<div id='test'>
  <input name="M1" size="3" value="1">
  <input name="M2" size="3" value="2">
  <input name="M3" size="3" value="3">
</div>
```

As a side note, if you're trying to build an array of `value`s from your inputs, you can use `Array.from()` with a mapping function on your `NodeList` like so:

```js
const test = document.getElementById('test');
const nodes = test.querySelectorAll('input');
const arr2 = Array.from(nodes, ({value}) => value);
console.log(arr2);
```

```html
<div id='test'>
  <input name="M1" size="3" value="1">
  <input name="M2" size="3" value="2">
  <input name="M3" size="3" value="3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

forEach should work:

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');
var arrInput = test.querySelectorAll('input');
var arr2 = [];

arrInput.forEach(element => {
    arr2.push(element.value);
})
console.log(arr2)
```

```html
<body>
    <div id='test'>
        <input name="M1" size="3" value="1">
        <input name="M2" size="3" value="2">
        <input name="M3" size="3" value="3">
    </div>
</body>
```